# Flag a yes or no if at least one value falls within different groupings

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, pivot

**Story:**

I need to see for each `name_id`, if they have at least one value that falls into the `continent_id category`.

So for `name_id` 1, he has at least one `country_id` within `continent_id` 1,2,3.
While `name_id` 2 has at least one `country_id` within `continent_id` 1,3.

**Data:**

```
+---------+------------+
| name_id | country_id |
+---------+------------+
|       1 |         10 |
|       1 |         11 |
|       1 |         12 |
|       1 |         20 |
|       1 |         21 |
|       1 |         30 |
|       2 |         10 |
|       2 |         30 |
+---------+------------+


+------------+--------------+
| country_id | continent_id |
+------------+--------------+
|         10 |            1 |
|         11 |            1 |
|         12 |            1 |
|         20 |            2 |
|         21 |            2 |
|         30 |            3 |
+------------+--------------+
```

**Desired Output:**

```
+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| name_id | continent_1 | continent_2 | continent_3 |
+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|       1 | YES         | YES         | YES         |
|       2 | YES         | NO          | YES         |
+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

**Objective:**

I need a table that for each `name_id`, I have a flag for yes or no per grouping of `continent_id`.

**What I tried:**

I started left join 3 times for each continent and using case statements but was wondering if there was a more efficient way of doing this if the actual tables contains millions of data.

**Fiddle:**

```
create table #t1 (name_id int,country_id varchar(20))
insert into #t1 values 
(1,10),
(1,11),
(1,12),
(1,20),
(1,21),
(1,30),
(2,10),
(2,30)

create table #t2 (country_id int,continent_id varchar(20))
insert into #t2 values 
(10,1),
(11,1),
(12,1),
(20,2),
(21,2),
(30,3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    n.name_id,
    case when max(case when c.continent_id = 1 then 1 end) = 1 
        then 'YES' 
        else 'NO' 
    end continent_1,
    case when max(case when c.continent_id = 2 then 1 end) = 1 
        then 'YES' 
        else 'NO' 
    end continent_2,
    case when max(case when c.continent_id = 3 then 1 end) = 1 
        then 'YES' 
        else 'NO' 
    end continent_3
from #t1 n
left join #t2 c on c.country_id = n.country_id
group by n.name_id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e0007ad78fa8dc487d28bf2c13e38f5b)**:

```
name_id | continent_1 | continent_2 | continent_3
------: | :---------- | :---------- | :----------
      1 | YES         | YES         | YES        
      2 | YES         | NO          | YES
```

Comment: brilliant use of max within case statement